# Discover windows in current KDE activity with d-bus

Tags: kde, d-bus

I want a hotkey to start a new konsole session, new chrome tab etc. I can just bind a global hotkey to a KDE command to do it. For example, here's a script that starts a new Konsole session:

```
#!/bin/bash
kon=$(qdbus org.kde.konsole*)
if [ -n "$kon" ]; then
        qdbus "$kon" /Konsole newSession
else
        konsole
fi
```

The problem is, when you're using a KDE activity this can be opening a new Konsole tab on another activity. I would like to detect this and create a new Konsole window in that case. Is this possible? The org.kde.kactivitymanagerd d-bus endpoint doesn't seem to have anything here.

Comment: What exactly you are searching for? Do you want check current activity or enumerate Konsole sessions?

Comment: @Hubbitus actually I went back to OS X, but the idea was to press a hotkey and always get a new konsole session in the current activity, whether in a tab or in a new window.